# How to Convert DateTime[] dates = datelist.ToArray(); to display only Date in C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I have an array of DateTime. But I want the result to display only dates. The array in which datetime is stored is:

```
DateTime[] dates = datelist.ToArray();
```

I am displaying this array in a label after converting to String as:

```
lblDate.Text = string.Join(", ", dates);
```

**Note**: I have tried all the possible solutions of converting the date in **ToString()** and using **DateTime.ParseExact** but nothing is working.

Comment: "I have tried all the possible solutions of converting the date in ToString()" - I am pretty sure you haven't. Why don't you tell us what you have tried for converting dates to strings? Or have you only found the one overload for ToString? If so then go look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: A DateTime contains always a Time part. If you don't want to display the Time part you apply a conversion to a string with something like date.ToShortDateString()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the format of DateTime when converting it to a string easily enough. Try something like this:

```
lblDate.Text = string.Join(", ", dates.Select(d => d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")));
```

Where d, M, y are day, month, year.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean but could simply format the date thus:

```
lblDate.Text = string.Join(", ", datelist.Select(d => d.ToString("YourFormatHere"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also convert in date format with use of format provider as below. it is better way.

```
labelDate.text = string.Join(",",dates.Select(d => d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
```